# How to remove error:-hardcoded string button should use @string resource in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

The error appears when we create a second main.java file to connect it with intial main_activity file?

Comment: Kind of irrelevant to the question, more feedback for SO, but I hate the term "not a real question". This is a perfectly "real" question, just a very unclear one.

Answer (score 7):

Add this to xml:
tools:ignore="HardcodedText"

Example:

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text" 
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
```

Comment: tools:ignore="HardcodedText" has its purpose, but having hardcoded text can cause lots of problems with internationalization and consistency. If you have multiple layouts you for the same fragment/activity (portrait and landscape for both phone and tablet) you'll be very troublesome. Changing the button caption will require you to change all of the other layouts manually. Having they all point to a @string resource requires only one change.

Comment: @ebarrenechea True, but many apps are never going to be localized (e.g. US only weather radar app), causing warnings for every time a non hard-coded string is used to be useless clutter in the warnings + errors window.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can just open your layout file and right click on the button (or any other view with text) and select `Edit Text`. From there just select one of the values from the list. If the value you want is not on the list then click on `New String...` to create a new android string. All your strings are defined in `strings.xml` inside your res/values folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the name of your button. You have to use the strings.xml file in values folder to set the name and use it on Button using @string/(name specified in string.xml file) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The string for the button should be in your strings.xml inside res/values. This then then means that you can have a strings.xml file for each language your app will support and the correct language will be used based on what locale their device is set to.

A simple way to create the string is if you highlight your hard coded string and then go to the menu > refactor > extract android string (It's something similar, I can't remember exactly at the top of my head) and then it will ask you what to the call new string and place it in the string.xml and replace your hard coded string with @string/your_string_name.